# Crazy Prolog Syntax

Tags: syntax, prolog

Being a curious guy, I found out that the following statements
which abuse special characters are syntactically correct:

```
X=(a,a).             
X=(a;a).             
X=(a|a).
X=a:a.             
X=a?a.
```

(As you see, the last two don't even need parentheses. Bonus weirdo points for ? being left- and `:|,;` being right-associative. Super bonus for sorting them by binding strength.)
They are not pairs like `[a|a]`. They are not atoms like `a_a`. They are not variables. They are not booleans like `a=a`. They are not terms like `a+a` (or at least I can't insert them into a meaningful computation).
What monsters did I create?

Comment: You are using infix **operators**. Use `write_canonical/1` on these terms to see how they look like in canonical notation. The right hand sides are *all* terms with arity 2 and different functors. Put differently, why do you think `a+a` is different? It's a term with functor `+` and 2 arguments.

Comment: @mat: That should probably be an answer.

Comment: The `?` as infix is specific to SWI. But all others are standard operators.

Comment: `a=a` is not a Boolean. It is a symbolic term, like all the other terms you're showing. Its interpretation depends on context. Used as a goal it will check the equality and *succeed* (not "return `True`"); similarly `X is 1+2` will treat the symbolic term `+(1,2)` as an arithmetic expression and unify `X` with the result of its *arithmetic evaluation*, `3`. You have discovered that Prolog is an ultimate symbolic programming language, where everything (i.e. every term) is unevaluated by default. ("quoted", speaking in Lisp; but there is no need to quote anything in Prolog).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the things you say about these terms are **true**, but the following is *false*:

> They are not terms like `a+a` (or at least I can't insert them into a meaningful computation).

Both statements are **false**:

First of all, **these are terms**, just like `a+a` is *also* a term. In all cases you show, you are using infix **operators**, just as in `a+a`.

If you are ever unsure about what you are actually writing down, use `write_canonical/1` to obtain the **canonical** representation of any Prolog term.

For example:

```
?- write_canonical(a+a).
+(a,a)
```

Aha! So `a+a` is a term with functor `+` and two arguments.

Another example:

```
?- write_canonical((a,a)).
','(a,a)
```

One of your examples contains this term as a subterm:

```
?- write_canonical(X=(a,a)).
=(_,','(a,a))
```

From your examples, it is not clear whether you are actually *posting* these terms as Prolog *goals*, or using them as Prolog *facts*. No matter: In any case, these are simply terms like any other terms that occur in Prolog: They have a functor and a number of arguments.

See alse `current_op/3` for more information. For example:

```
?- current_op(P, T, :).
P = 600,
T = xfy.
```

I leave figuring out what `600` and `xfy` means in this case as an exercise for you. Every Prolog system comes with a number of **predefined** operators. If that were not the case, then we would have to write all terms in *prefix* notation <sub>(which would make Prolog code as unreadable as Lisp, and we would probably also tell ourselves constantly that that's a good thing and act as if infix syntax were not more readable in many cases)</sub>.

As to your other statements:

> They are not pairs like `[a|a]`

First of all:

```
| ?- write_canonical([a|a]).
'.'(a,a)
```

So `[a|a]` is a term with functor `.` and two arguments. It is *not* a list, because `a` (the second argument) is *not* a list. However, by convention, the functor `-` is typically used to denote *pairs* in Prolog, so one would rather write a pair as `a-a` in this case.

> They are not booleans like `a=a`. They are not terms like `a+a`

Again, please see:

```
?- write_canonical(a=a).
=(a,a)
```

Here, you are already using the "*crazy*" syntax quite naturally. It's **the same** concept as in all the examples you give: `(=)/2` and `(+)/2` are infix **operators** in Prolog, and so you can use infix notation to denote the terms that you would otherwise have to write as `=(a,a)` and `+(a,a)`, respectively.

And of course you can use **all these terms** in any meaningful computation, **just like any other term**.

The ability to define custom operators is a major attraction of Prolog in some applications, and lets you write Prolog code that fits your problem domain very well in some situations. Several Prolog libraries also export custom operators that extend plain Prolog with more declarative features in a way that naturally fits into the language. Constraint solvers like CLP(FD) are a prime example of this, notably exporting the operators `(#=)/2`, `(#<)/2` etc. so that you can simply write `X #= Y` to denote the term `#=(X, Y)`.

Comment: Some of this I realized myself (stupid me :-) when it finally dawned me that a variable must not be an integer - it can be a boolean. (I know infix notation. The "crazy" referred to |:? being used in other circumstances.) So a comma/semicolon are simply and/or, like in goals. THX for pointing me to write_canonical. And - is overloaded to denote pairs? Noone told me that im my Prolog course...Still, this leaves the *semantics* of |:?... : works with booleans, a:true is true, a:false is false. SWIPL Online is no help here (since I can't search for it).

Comment: Logically, a variable stands for *any term at all*. Please consider carefully what this means, and enumerate possible cases to get a better understanding what a Prolog term is. `(-)/2` is *by convention* used for pairs in Prolog. Several predicates like `keysort/2` use `(-)/2` for this purpose, and also libraries like `library(pairs)`, `library(assoc)` etc. found in several Prolog systems use `(-)/2` for pairs. Please note that there is *no inherent semantics* of Prolog terms. You use *predicates* to define the relations. Please see my profile page for a few references that I hope help you.

Comment: THX, this comes in handy for my Prolog exam next week. :-) (Although they surely won't ask what : "usually" does. They won't ask about : at all, it's more Prolog 101A. I found it on StOv, it's for defining modules. And I also found the handy current_op/3 showing all operators.)

Comment: Well, in almost all Prolog programs, you **still** use at least one operator, namely `(:-)/2`, so you should know about infix operators. Without operators, you would have to write rules as `:-(Head, Body)` instead of `Head :- Body`.